# ionic 3 : Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND logo.png

Tags: android, css, html, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm building ionic 3 app, I have simple login page work perfectly in web mode but when I run it on android the logo doesn't appear.

[image]

[image]

here is the login page code :

```
<ion-content padding style="background:url('assets/imgs/bg.jpg') no-repeat center;background-size:cover;" id="page1">
    <div class="header padding text-center">
        <img src="../../assets/img/logo.png" alt="DoggyDOG" />
    </div>
    <form id="login-form1">
        <ion-item id="login-input3">
            <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <div class="spacer" style="width:30px;height:11px;" id="login-spacer3"></div>
        <ion-item id="login-input2">
            <ion-input type="password" placehol3er="Password" name="password"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <div class="spacer" style="height:10px;" id="login-spacer2"></div>
        <button id="login-button1" ion-button outline color="energized" block icon-left style="font-weight:500;color:#ffffff;">
            <ion-icon ios="ios-log-in" md="md-log-in"></ion-icon>      
            Login
         </button>
        <div class="spacer" style="height:50px;" id="login-spacer3"></div>
        <button id="login-button2" ion-button block color="light" icon-left style="color:#3A539B;">
         <ion-icon left ios="logo-facebook" md="logo-facebook"></ion-icon>
        Facebook
        </button>
        <button id="login-button3" ion-button block color="googlebtn" icon-right style="color:#ffffff;">  
         <ion-icon ios="logo-google" md="logo-google"></ion-icon>
        Google
        </button>
    </form>

</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your background is successfully loaded without `../../` in path, try without it:

```
<img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="DoggyDOG" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your help